# Add/Remove class from img within containing li

Tags: jquery

I have a series of li's that each contain an image and a related text link. Both image and text link to the same page. When you hover over the image, I currently have CSS transitions setup to adjust the border radius, and return back when you roll off. However, the same doesn't happen when you hover over the text link, and I would like that to happen.

So I created a hover class (.customerimagehover) for the image (.customerimage) that I want to trigger when you hover over the text link (.customertitle).

Tried my hand at it, but nothing happens on hovering over the text link. Pretty sure my syntax is off, not a jQuery/JS whiz. If someone could steer me in the right direction, that would be great.

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><img class="customerimage" src="#"></a><br/>
    <a class="customertitle" href="#">Customer Title</a>
</li>

<script>
    $('.customertitle').hover.closest('img').removeClass('customerimage').addClass('customerimagehover');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.customertitle').hover(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').find('img').removeClass('customerimage').addClass('customerimagehover');
});
```

---

[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

---

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Kx2ck/)

```
$('.customertitle').hover(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').find('img').toggleClass('customerimage  customerimagehover');
});
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks for the jsfiddle, that's what I was eventually going to get to, but totally forgot about toggleClass.

Thank you very much. I'd upvote but I still don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just use css :hover option! It will be better!

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work. I am using css :hover combined with transitions in the css rules when you hover over the image, but I needed it to also act when hovering over a different element, which :hover or any css cannot do.